# How can I wrap the C++ <algorithm> library with Cython?

Tags: c++, cythonize

I have some code from a colleague using `cython.weave` to wrap a function from a C++ library:

```
def partialsort(a, K):
    support_code = "#include <algorithm>"
    code = "std::partial_sort (&ak(0), &ak(K), &ak(N));"
    N = len(a)
    ak = a.copy()
    vars = ['ak', 'K', 'N']
    s = weave.inline(code, vars, support_code=support_code,
                     type_converters=converters.blitz)
```

With the Weave tool gone I would like to replace this by Cython, if possible. So far I have tried my luck based on http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html and attempted the following in a Cython module, just to check if I can access the library at all:

```
cdef extern from "<algorithm>":
    pass
```

When I try to build the Cython module, I get following error:

```
csorting.c:604:10: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or `folder
 #include <algorithm>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

As far as I can understand, `<algorithm>` is a C++ library. Is C++ the problem here? I have `g++`, but the Cython build set-up uses `gcc`. Is `<algorithm>` a library that has to be installed individually?

Comment: Have you [configured](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) Cython for C++?

Comment: Probably not. I'll look into how, thanks